# Can I query all the boolean properties on a C# object at once, looking for a single match?

Tags: c#, linq

Imaginary object:

```
public class ImaginaryObject
{
    int objectId { get; set; }
    string name { get; set; }
    bool b1 { get; set; }
    bool b2 { get; set; }
    bool b3 { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any way I can write a single query, *without naming any of the fields on the object*, returning a boolean value, which is true if *any* of the boolean values on the object are true, otherwise false?

(Tagged with Linq, because I suspect that'll be part of the answer, if it's possible)

Comment: Use reflection to get the property types.

Comment: If you do not want to delve that deep with reflection, why not adding a private property that is the result of a logical OR on all the others ? like `bool result = b1 || b2 || b3 ...`

Comment: @Veverke because I'd prefer not to use the property names if at all possible.

Comment: Whenever you have such a requirement which leads to a reflection approach you know you've done something wrong. In this case those boolean properties belong into one `bool[]`(or list)

Comment: Or better, what Tim Schmelter suggested. Now the boolean variable names is irrelevant.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Normally, I'd agree. In this instance, these are EF properties and there's a good chance they will change frequently. There's also a good reason for the table to have a big list of boolean values. I'm trying to minimise the need for maintenance. Maybe it's still the wrong approach, IDK.

Comment: @MattThrower Then your question seems to be lacking a context. The reflection based answers cannot be used to form `Where` clause of `IQueryable<ImaginaryObject>` in EF if that was your intention.

Comment: @MattThrower: then the design issue is even worse, you have to fix the database-model. Create another table that references the main table via foreign key. It's more efficient, better to maintain and easier to write readable queries(no matter if LINQ or sql). Entity framework will automatically create a collection-property which allows to query these booleans.

Comment: @TimSchmelter well, this is getting difficult. It's not my DB design - I was assured by a (normally competent) DBA that the design chosen was the fastest for the intended purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `GetType()` and `GetProperties()` methods from `System.Reflection` namespace for dynamically getting details of the type object belongs.

```
var booleanProperties = imaginaryObject.GetType()
     .GetProperties()
     .Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(Boolean));

foreach(var prop in booleanProperties) 
{
    if((bool)prop.GetValue(imaginaryObject, null) == true)
        return true;
}
```

Or simply with LINQ:

```
 var isAnyTrue= imaginaryObject.GetType()
       .GetProperties()
       .Where(prop => prop.PropertyType == typeof(Boolean))
       .Any(prop => (bool)prop.GetValue(imaginaryObject, null));
```